# Update existing record in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create the following in CakePHP:

Starting page: User enters a loginname which pre exists in the DB. Table name loginname.
Once the user has entered the right loginname, the user continues to the registration form, where the user can add personal data to the existing record.

When the user saves the form, the record with only the loginname has personal data added.

This is what i have:

Logic for starting page:

```
    public function checkCodeRespondent() {

    //set var
    $password = $this->data['Respondent']['loginname'];

    //set condition for hasAny function
    $condition = array('Respondent.loginname'=>$password);

    //if password matches continue to registreer
    if($this->Respondent->hasAny($condition)){
        //find data by password
        $respondent = $this->findByPass($password);
        //set var for current id
        $id= $respondent['Respondent']['id'];
        //redirect with current id
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'aanmelden', $id));
    } else {
    //if password does not match, return to index with errormessage
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
    public function findByPass($pass) {

    $respondent = $this->Respondent->find('first', array('conditions' => array('pass' => $pass)));
    return $respondent;
}
```

And this is the logic for saving the data to the record:

```
public function registreren() {
    if($this->request->isPost()) {

        $this->Respondent->id = $id;
        if ($this->Respondent->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

        } else {

        }
    }
```

I thought i got my id through the function checkCodeRespondent() , but that's not working. What am i forgetting or what am i doing wrong? If i need to give more info, i'm happy to help ofcourse.

Update: I read that i need to add `echo $form->input('id');`, only when i `debug($this->request);` the id value is empty. What do i need to change in my code?

Comment: Within function registreren() you are doing, 
$this->Respondent->id = $id; where is this $id comming from ?? 
or are you trying to sending $id as function parameter like registreren($id) ??

Comment: I understand that normally you would get the id from the url, but i can't figure it out for myself, how i can get the id without using the url. 
I added a hidden input field with id and that's why i tried to use  $this->Respondent->id to retrieve the id. But it's not working. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added hidden field for id then just replace:

```
$this->Respondent->id = $id;
```

By:

```
$this->Respondent->id = $this->request->data['Respondent']['id'];
And in your view, give name="data[Respondent][id]" in the hidden field of id like:
<input type="hidden" name="data[Respondent][id]" value="value of id">
```

that should work fine for you if no other issues out there.

Comment: Damn it's that easy haha. Thank you very much! Really appreciate you takin the time to help me :)